# Debugging Android JUnit JNI calls through Java

Tags: android, c++, debugging, gdb

Has anyone debugged Android Java code  running under an Android JUnit test case stepping into and out of JNI C++ code which is located in a library project? Is it possible? If so how does it work? In my setup I have an Android JUnit test which executes a component in a library project. I also have a Java breakpoint in my setup and I had to hack the ndk-gdb script to work around "run-as" not working on my 4.3 Galaxy Nexus. I also hacked my main project adding sym links to the libs and jni folders in my main project just to satisfy the ndk-gdb script. Running ndk-gdb drops me into what looks like a remote gdb session. When I attempt to set a breakpoint in my cpp code I get an error stating the symbol tables have not been loaded.

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?
```

I have set android:debuggable="true" in my main project, lib project, and test project Manifest files. I'm pretty sure that loadLibrary has already been called as my breakpoint happens after my JNI object with the static loadLibrary call is instantiated. What else should I look for?

Comment: Would love to know a working solution for this as well.